# Converter BGR para RGB (Opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

Possuo um código que encontra as bordas em volta do que foi rotulado na imagem e coloca o valor de -1 nos pixeis dessa borda encontrada.
Estou com problemas na hora de converter a imagem já com as bordas com -1 no seu valor, de BGR para RGB. pois ao tentar converter, o valor -1 é perdido e apenas encontro valores 0 (resto) e 255 (rotulado) na imagem salva.
Queria manter os valores 0, -1, 255 ao salvar a imagem em formato RGB.

**Segue código:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image

def mostrar_imagem(img):
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

img = cv2.imread('framepng/frame24.png',0)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations = 1)
img = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations = 1)

_, binario = cv2.threshold(img, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

copia = img.copy()

tmp = cv2.findContours(binario, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contornos = tmp[0] if len(tmp) == 2 else tmp[1]

img_contornos = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
mostrar_imagem(img_contornos)

cv2.drawContours(img_contornos, contornos, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
mask = cv2.inRange(img_contornos, (0, 254, 0), (0, 255, 0))
mostrar_imagem(mask)

binario = np.int16(binario)
binario[mask == 255] = -1
binario = np.ma.masked_where(binario == -1, binario)

cmap = matplotlib.cm.Greys  # Can be any colormap that you want after the cm
cmap.set_bad(color='red')

plt.show()
matplotlib.image.imsave('framepng-1/teste3.png', binario)
```

Comment: Tente converter a imagem para RGB antes the usar matplotlib para salvar a imagem.

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso, porem como eu disse apos fazer isso o valor de -1 que é da borda que eu mencionei acima é perdido.
A imagem atual que possuo dentro da variável binário esta com as cores roxo (resto), branco (borda), amarelo (rotulado), a minha intenção é apenas trocar as cores, colocando como roxo = preto, branco e amarelo = branco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problema

Com `img = cv2.imread('framepng/frame24.png',0)` a imagem é convertida para escala de cinza, pois a flag 0 é utilizada. Com isso, você perde toda a informação de cores que estava presente da imagem.

Seguem as flags de modos da função `imread()`:

```
cv::ImreadModes {
  cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED = -1,
  cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE = 0,
  cv::IMREAD_COLOR = 1,
  cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH = 2,
  cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR = 4,
  cv::IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL = 8,
  cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2 = 16,
  cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2 = 17,
  cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_4 = 32,
  cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_4 = 33,
  cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_8 = 64,
  cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_8 = 65,
  cv::IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION = 128
}
```

#### Solução

Se a sua imagem estiver em BGR e quiser converter para RGB, basta utilizar a seguinte função do Python:

```
img = img[:,:,::-1]
```

Ou para melhorar a compreensão do código:

```
img_bgr = img_rgb[:,:,::-1]
```

Pois uma imagem é uma matriz, com valores de intensidade em cada coordenada de cada pixel. No caso do espaço de cores RGB, cada pixel possuirá um vetor com 3 canais de cores, ou seja, 3 valores. Então `::-1` é utilizado para inverter a ordem destes valores.

Ou a conversão diretamente pela função do OpenCV:

```
img_rgb= cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Mas creio que isso não resolveria o seu problema do modo que o código está apresentado, o que deve ser realizado é a leitura da imagem como colorida `img = cv2.imread('framepng/frame24.png',1)` ou da imagem original `img = cv2.imread('framepng/frame24.png',-1)`. E depois converter esta imagem para escala de cinza com outro nome de variável, como por exemplo, `cinza = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`. Assim a imagem colorida/original é mantida na memória e pode ser manipulada posteriormente.

Isto é, o espaço de cores utilizado no código é em escala de cinza (1 canal) e não o BGR (3 canais). Porque as funções utilizadas, como operações morfológicas (erode e dilate), entre outras, são utilizadas em escala de cinza e precisam de uma imagem nesse espaço de cores como entrada. Então a conversão de BGR para RGB não resolveria o seu problema, pois o problema não é esse.

E ao adicionar o valor de -1 à imagem colorida de 3 canais, não seria possível utilizar as funções do OpenCV, pois a sua matriz seria híbrida com alguns pixels com 3 componentes e outros com 1 componente. Gerando mais erros em futuros processamentos nesta imagem, o que pode ser realizado é a inserção de -1 em um dos canais ou nos 3 canais, para manter a imagem com 3 canais.

> Leia um pouco sobre os [espaços de
>   cores](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=espa%C3%A7os+de+cores+opencv)

Comment: Fazendo um debug completo, acredito que a minha imagem dentro de binário está em escala de cinza, a real intenção era voltar as cores originais de preto e branco, mas mantendo as alterações feitas como colocar a borda um valor de -1. Seria possível essa modificações de cores? Tentei diversas maneiras mas não consigo manter o valor, acho que pelo fato de tentar converter uma imagem de 1 canal em 3 canais e esse valor acabar se perdendo, como você disse no ultimo paragrafo. Seria então necessário trabalhar e manter uma imagem de 3 canais?

Comment: Sim, manter com 3 canais. Mas você está inserindo -1, porque provavelmente utiliza uma função de alguma biblioteca que necessita como entrada uma imagem de somente 1 canal.

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo. Você tem alguma sugestão de alteração deste código para que ele continue funcionando, porem com 3 canais (mantendo o valor de -1 nos contornos), ainda estou no começo de processamento de imagens e não possuo muita noção.

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa subtituir pelo codigo abaixo realizando a troca da variavel padrão da imagem por uma variavel_rgb, coloquei como variavel mas vai depender do nome que colocou.

variavel_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(variavel, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(variavel_rgb)